# Micrsoft Excel. The Last Modified By field is not updating

Tags: excel, openxml

When a user modifies and saves a spreadsheet the Last Modified By, as accessed via the INFO tab, is not being set. It is displayed as "D3I3t3M3" instead of who made the modification. This used to work before I began using ClosedXML to programmatically populate the worksheet.

[image]

I have examined security settings on the spreadsheet. I have searched for a setting withing the workbook in OpenXml in my code and have found nothing interesting. I have validated Account Security on the workbood and spreadsheet.

Comment: For what it's worth here is the code...

Comment: // New  up the FLASH Excel template
                    
                    XLWorkbook restBook = new XLWorkbook(FLASHFOLDER + "FlashReportTemplateBudget.xlsx");
                    IXLWorksheet restSheet = restBook.Worksheet("WithBudget");

Comment: ... <code that populates the spreadsheet>...

Comment: ...restBook.SaveAs(FLASHFOLDER + FLASHREPORTNAME + Enums.AudienceEnum.FlashSlots.ToString() + dtReportDate.ToString("MMddyyyy") + FLASHREPORTEXT);

Comment: Clarity: The users wanted the LastModiefy By field set in the workbook itself where it is viewed from file..info..

Answer (score 0):

I did this by setting that field from Windows.Secirty programmatically, in the app itself. (ASP.NET CORE)

XLWorkbook restBook = new XLWorkbook(FLASHFOLDER + "FlashReportTemplateBudget.xlsx");

restBook.Properties.LastModifiedBy = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();

Please make sure your have the following...
using System;

Comment: Sorry. This only works inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to get the current user of an ASP.NET C# Web application - even when running on IIS I have personally validated this solution after hours of trying many other options mentioned in my research.

.Properties.LastModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;

Please be sure that Authentication for web app on IIS includes Windows Authentication. Also, be sure that your Program.cs file includes... using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate; . . . builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy. options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; });